# Python: How can I sum integers in a CSV file, while only summing the integers of a certain variable?

Tags: python, windows, list, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to program some data in a csvfile by using Python. I have a list of countries and results of the Eurovision Songcontest, and it looks like this:

```
Country,Points,Year
Belgium;181;2016
Netherlands;153;2016
Australia;511;2016
Belgium;217;2015
Australia;196;2015
```

Et cetera.

In summary, I want to sum the total of points that any country received throughout the years, so the output should look something like this:
'Belgium: 398','Netherlands: 153','Australia: 707' and so on.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import csv
with open('euro20042016.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    pointsallyears = []
    countriesallyears = []
    readFILE = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in readFILE:
        countriesallyears.append(row[0])
        pointsallyears.append(row[1])
csvfile.close()

results = []
for result in pointsallyears:
    result = int(result)
    results.append(result)

scorebord = zip(countriesallyears,results)
```

So I already made sure that the results / points are actual integers and I filtered out the third row (Year), but I have no idea how to proceed from here. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to read the file line by line manually? This is something elementary that can be done in `pandas`: http://pandas.pydata.org/ (two lines: read csv and groupby).

Answer (score 1):

Just put @Mikk's comment into an actual answer. Two lines except the `import`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('euro20042016.csv', sep = ';')
print df.groupby('Country')['Points'].sum()
```

The only extra thing you need to do is to change the first line of your file to be delimited by `;` instead of `,`.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed your code to use a dictionary and used country names as keys. In result dictionary d will have country names as key and value is the total points.

```
import csv

d = dict()

with open('euro20042016.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    readFILE = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    print (readFILE)
    c_list = []
    for row in readFILE:
        if row[0] in c_list:
            d[row[0]] = d[row[0]] + int(row[1])
        else:
            c_list.append(row[0])
            d[row[0]] = int(row[1])
csvfile.close()

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to play around a bit with your code, and this is what I came up with. Here, `row[0]` contains the country names, and `row[1]` contains the values we need. We check if the country already exists in the dictionary we use to maintain the aggregates, and if it doesn't we create it.

```
import csv
with open('euro20042016.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
score_dict={}
readFILE = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
for row in readFILE:
    # Only rows with 3 elements have the data we need
    if len(row) == 3:
        if row[0] in score_dict:
            score_dict[row[0]]+=int(row[1])
        else:
            score_dict[row[0]]=int(row[1])
csvfile.close()
print score_dict
```

What I get as output is this

```
{'Belgium': 398, 'Australia': 707, 'Netherlands': 153}
```

which I believe is what you were aiming for.

Let me know in the comments if you face a problem understanding anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution of that. but make sure your euro20042016.csv file same as

```
Belgium;181;2016
Netherlands;153;2016
Australia;511;2016
Belgium;217;2015
Australia;196;2015
```

and this code get output in list. like

```
[('Belgium', 398), ('Australia', 707), ('Netherlands', 153)]
```

Code is here

```
try:
    f = open('euro20042016.csv', 'r+')
    s = f.read()

    lst = list(map(lambda x: x.split(';'), s.split('\n')))

    points, country = [], []
    for line in lst:
        points.append(int(line[1]))
        country.append(line[0])

    countrypoints = sorted(zip(country, points), key=lambda x: x[1])
    country = list(set(country))
    total = [0]*len(country)

    for rec in countrypoints:
        total[country.index(rec[0])] = total[country.index(
            rec[0])] + rec[1]
    f.close()
    finalTotal = list(zip(country, total))
    print finalTotal

except IOError as ex:
    print ex
except Exception as ex:
    print ex
```

I hope this will help you.